# Mysql databases. Delete all tables with foreign keys. Copy all tables

Tags: mysql

I have two databases.
First database is used by site.
Second is used for debuging by test site.

Several times per day I have to update test site database.

I don't have root access to drop and create debug database.
So I have to drop all tables ignoring foreign keys; backup and restore tables from firts database to second.

All tables are InnoDB with foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=root
PASSWORD=xxx
DBFROM=xxx
DBTO=xxx
HOST=localhost

MYSQL_OPTS="-u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -h $HOST"

TABLES=$(mysql $MYSQL_OPTS -BNe "show tables" $DBTO | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//' | awk '{print "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " $1 ";SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"}')
mysql $MYSQL_OPTS -BNe "$TABLES" $DBTO
mysqldump $MYSQL_OPTS $DBFROM | mysql $MYSQL_OPTS $DBTO
```